# Contenido multilenguaje dinámico en Android

Tags: android, webservice, internacionalización

Buenas, cómo puedo obtener el idioma que está configurado en el móvil? Necesito hacer una app multilenguaje y entiendo perfectamente como implementar los string.xml para la parte estática. Ahora bien, qué pasa si tengo contenido dinámico? puedo obtener la info a través de un web service según el idioma configurado? a eso iba con la pregunta inicial.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el idioma configurado en el dispositivo, puedes hacerlo con:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Sobre traer el contenido *dinámico* desde un WebService al que pases, por ejemplo, el valor devuelto por esta llamada, si que es posible y la idea me parece correcta. Tendrás que avanzar más en tu proyecto y volver con dudas puntuales si necesitas de alguna ayuda adicional.

Answer (score 1):

¿Como puedes obtener la información a través de un Web Service según el idioma configurado?

Para realizar esto tu método debe estar preparado para que en base a un valor que defina un lenguaje y que tu envíes al Web Service, regrese determinada respuesta con contenido en otro lenguaje.

En base a esto obtendrías  contenido en diferente idioma para usar en la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]